# He is getting admitted in a college vs. He is being admitted in a college

Tags: causative-get

As far as I know, get is used when u want something to be done by someone else. And Be is used for passive. But here which one should be used. And if both are correct, then someone can point me to a site which can tell me the exact difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

"Being admitted" would be the common usage.  That would imply that "he" met all of the requirements, and the process of admission was underway.

As you point out in the question, "getting" can have a connotation that someone else is driving the action.  "Getting admitted" isn't common usage, but it could imply, for example:

- "He" didn't meet all of the requirements, but someone else intervened to make it happen.
- There was some kind of mess up and the routine admission procedures didn't work.  Admission is happening because someone intervened and straightened it out.

Answer (score 0):

get would mean **becoming** in this context and does not work.

He is **being admitted to** the college. **Because you cannot become admitted**.

Comment: In this case I disagree, ... most definitely it is a process. Have you never been admitted to a hospital?

Comment: "He is getting admitted to the hospital" might be what what you say in response to: "Where's John?" But better is: He's being admitted to the hospital which is why he's not here.

Comment: You're spot on in correcting *in* to *to*, anyway.

Comment: I find it useful for very colloquial speech but not for more standard speech.